# Canvas is not covering the whole screen

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-canvas

I am using an ImageView to create a canvas and draw elements with finger touch on it. But the problem is that, firstly the canvas only covers a little portion of the screen to draw or write something and secondly it produces lines or curves far away where I touch. I have one textview and the imageview in linear layout. Please check my code and help me for the same.

DrawTestActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
ImageView imageView;
Bitmap bitmap;
Canvas canvas;
Path path;
Paint paint;
float downx = 0, downy = 0, upx = 0, upy = 0;
float startX = 0;
float startY = 0;
float endX = 0;
float endY = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
 Point size = new Point();
 display.getSize(size);
 int width = size.x;
 int height = size.y;

 bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
 canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
 paint = new Paint();
 paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
 paint.setAntiAlias(true);
 paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
 paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
 paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  int action = event.getAction();
  switch (action) {
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
   startX=event.getX();
   startY=event.getY();
   break;

  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
   endX = event.getX();
   endY = event.getY();
   canvas.drawLine(startX,startY,endX,endY, paint);
   imageView.invalidate();
   startX=endX;
   startY=endY;
   break;

  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
   break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
   break;
  default:
   break;
}
 return true;
}
}
```

Comment: To check height and width, you can print it in logs.by function Log.i("Height",height).Place this after you assign display height to height variable.This will give you figure ,if you are getting actual height or not.

Comment: You can also use this method for android api level 10 and below.
DEVICE_HEIGHT=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

Comment: I have used this. But the result is same.

Comment: Have you cleared all margins and paddings of the ImageView? Also are it's width and height set to fill_parent?

Comment: There is no margins pr paddings in ImageView, and yes, its height and wight is set to fill_parent.